# Css grid box auto height with dynamic list

Tags: html, css

Hi im trying to make a list of my products

here is my sample code

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">1</div>
  <div class="grand-child">1</div>
  <div class="grand-child">1</div>
 </div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  <div class="grand-child">2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and for my css

```
.parent{
 display: grid;
 gap: 10px;
 grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) / repeat(4, 1fr);
 grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

What I want is to remove all its bottom spaces. like this
[image]

with use of anything. dont need to be grid. can be flex or any other.
also the count of child and grand child is dynamic depending on uploaded products and category.
child = category
grand-child = products

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flexbox` should work, but you'll need to specify the `max-height` so the elements wrap to the next column

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
    <div class="grand-child">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
    <div class="grand-child">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: big thanks. this is what im looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to fit this to in 4 columns and container height is also auto adjust? thanks

Comment: You can use `width` to specify the width of a column to like `25%` that should force the 4 columns, problem is when you do that you must specify a height, else it won't wrap to the column and if the specifications are too small, then more columns are created. Overflowing the parent's width.